# What's the correct way to terminate a thread that runs a WinForm application continously?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a unit test where I create a background thread that runs a standard WinForms application by calling [`Application.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157900(v=vs.110).aspx).

This is the creation of the thread:

```
var startSignal = new ManualResetEvent(false);

ThreadStart threadStart = () =>
        {
            syncContext = new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext();
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(syncContext);

            startSignal.Set();

            Application.Run();
        };

var thread = new Thread(threadStart)
             {
                 IsBackground = true,
             };

thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
```

In the `TearDown` method, I would like to terminate this thread. When I use `Thread.About`, I get a `ThreadAbortException`, even with a `try`/`catch` because the exception is re-thrown automatically according to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta(v=vs.110).aspx):

> `ThreadAbortException` is a special exception that can be caught by application code, but is re-thrown at the end of the `catch` block unless `ResetAbort` is called.

This exception that is thrown automatically is unhandled and it breaks other tests to run while using ReSharper test runner.

I though of using `thread.Join()`, but it never ends! Because the application message loop continues to run unless I call `Exit` or [`ExitThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.exitthread(v=vs.110).aspx) which I can't because all I have is the freakin `Thread` and I need to call them inside of the thread.

So, what should I do? How can I safely end this thread without getting an exception?

Comment: Old question, but since it's a background thread the CLR will not wait for the thread to end before terminating, which could cause the ThreadAbortException. Also, you could just use your own ManualResetEvent to wait and signal that from the outside. Just give it some time to wait for the message pumps to complete before ending. You could wait for 5 seconds before setting the MRE.

Answer (score 1):

You will need some kind of inter-thread communication to tell the WinForms thread to terminate itself.  Then, you use Thread.Join() with a timeout to wait for it to quit gracefully, and if it fails to join in that amount of time, you do Thread.Abort() to hard-kill it.

Since it is a WinForms thread, then it is likely spending the majority of its time in a message pump waiting for system messages to translate into events.  You can probably take advantage of this and send a `WM_QUIT` message to that thread's message pump to tell it to shutdown.  You would have to P/invoke `PostThreadMessage` to do that.  You can do this with nothing but the thread id.

If you can modify the WinForms thread code, then you could do something more managed and less p/invoke magic, such as use a `CancellationTokenSource` to signal quit, and have the main form of the WinForms thread subscribe to the `Token.Register` of the `CancellationTokenSource` and use that to notify that you want to quit.  Your control thread could then call the `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` method to signal to the WinForms thread that it should quit.

Comment: I will try the `WM_QUIT`, about the second suggestion: there is no form, Application.Run just "_Begins running a standard application message loop on the current thread, without a form._"